# Check if all new line separated strings exist in another sheet using a lookup column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an example sheet at: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VucCza1F1xi9s61MXBuOu_122yPyGjQdundYHipXnS4/edit?usp=sharing.

I have two sheets:

- `Sheet1` has a table with two columns:

  - `column 1` has a unique string
  - `column 2` has a new line separated strings
- `Sheet2` has a table with two columns:

  - `column 1` has a string
  - `column 2` has a string but no new lines

**Sheet1**

[image]

**Sheet2**

[image]

I want to put an `ARRAYFORMULA` in `Sheet1`.`column 3` that will tell me if all of the values in `Sheet1`.`column 2` for `Sheet1`.`column 1` have a matching row in `Sheet2`.

In my example sheet I have a column showing expected output and explanation.

Also, I am on Google Workspace Enterprise and won't have the new functions (`map`, `lambda`, etc...) for a while. So I need something that works without them.

Comment: Can we assume that the two sheets are sorted in any particular way?  In your example sheet all the values for alpha are sorted alphabetically (bravo, charlie, delta delta), but will that always be true?

Comment: And are we checking that both sheets are exactly equivalent? i.e. For a result of TRUE, each row in Sheet1 must have matching rows in Sheet2 AND each row in Sheet2 must be represented in Sheet1?  Or can there be extra rows in Sheet2 not represented in Sheet1 as long as all the values in Sheet1 are found in Sheet2?

Comment: You want to filter from both columns in `sheet2`?

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: @AaronDuniganAtLee 1) No. The data won't always be sorted. 2) It does not need to be two ways. The values in Sheet1 need to be in Sheet2. Don't care about what is in Sheet2 but not in Sheet1.

Comment: @Osm No. I don't need to filter. I am checking that values in Sheet1 are in Sheet2.

Comment: @TheMaster Good call out. I will fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain whether you're looking for a single array formula to place in cell C1 of Sheet1 (it sounds like that, but I'm not sure such a thing is possible).  It is possible to write a formula that can be copied down column C, that will generate the expected output in column F.  Here's the formula for C2:

```
=PRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(MATCH(SPLIT(B2,CHAR(10)),FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!A:A=A2),0),0)))>0
```

### Breakdown

`FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!A:A=A2)` creates an array of all the values in column B of Sheet2 that have a corresponding value of e.g. "alpha"  in column A (using the values in your example sheet).

`SPLIT(B2,CHAR(10))` creates an array of the individual newline-separated strings in cell B2.

`MATCH(..., ..., 0)` searches the second array for each value in the first array, and returns an array of indices showing where they are found (or an error if not found)

`IFERROR(..., 0)` converts the errors in that array to 0's.

`ARRAYFORMULA(...)` ensures that the above returns an array (if not present it only returns the first value in the array).

At this point we have an array whose values are 0 if the desired value was not found, non-zero if the value was found. We want to know whether ALL those values are non-zero.

`PRODUCT(...)` multiplies all those values together, and the result will be 0 if and only if some value was not found.  Hence the `>0` which returns TRUE if the result is non-zero and FALSE if 0.

### Assumptions

I'm assuming here that the search is only one-way.  i.e. If the values in column B of Sheet1 are a subset of the values in Sheet2, my formula will still return TRUE and will not notice if there are extraneous values in Sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this formula**

```
=IF(A2="",,IFNA(
           IF(ISTEXT(FILTER(
                     CONCAT(Sheet2!$A$2:$A,Sheet2!$B$2:$B),
                     CONCAT(Sheet2!$A$2:$A,Sheet2!$B$2:$B)=
                     CONCAT(A2,B2))),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want to have to put the formula multiples for each row. I want an `arrayformula` that checks every row.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  {"Output";
    MAP(A2:A7,B2:B7,
    LAMBDA(a,b,
      BYROW(
        a=XLOOKUP(
          SPLIT(b,CHAR(10)),Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!A:A
        ),
        LAMBDA(x,IFNA(AND(x),FALSE))
      )
    )
    )
  }
)
```

- `SPLIT` column `b` by new lines `CHAR(10)`
- `LOOKUP` each of those  words in `Sheet2`  and see if the result is equal to column `a`
- Aggregate the boolean results for each `ROW` with `AND`
- Repeat the process for all the cells in range `A2:B7` using `MAP`

Comment: Yay new functions 

Comment: I should have included that I am on Enterprise and don't have the new functions yet. I won't have them for a while I think. :(